# Xcode: how to make a launchScreen storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I m new in xcode, and right now i just need to build a launchScreen storyboard. but i don't know how to do this simple think :

I need to put an image at exactly 20 pixels from the bottom of the status bar (and in the launchscreen the status bar seen to be transparent i don't know if it's matter). I also need to center horizontally this image (look easy but didn't find yet how to do)

Someone can help me to do this ?

I also have 4 version of my image for different scale factor (1x, 2x, 3x and even 4x) but I don't know how (and if it's possible) to set up an image dedicated for a particular scale factor. I even don't know how to import a image in my launchScreen :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The launch screen is available as an image asset in the `Assets.xcassets` folder within your project. You can link same image with multiple scaled versions(1x, 2x and 3x) referenced under a single name.

[image]

If not available by default, just create a new image asset with any name and specify this under the `Launch Images Source` tab in your targets `General settings`.

[image]

Alternatively, latest xcode versions suggest use of a launch screen storyboard. This comes under the default file name `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. You can create a scene here as you normally do in storyboards and specify it as the launch screen.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The LaunchScreen is created by default when starting new projects.
You can add it in existing project too.

It's a nib where you can pub an `UIImageView` linked to you base image, with @2x and @3x image.
You also can use the SizeClass to set customize your LaunchScreen

Answer (score 0):

If your deployment target of application is less then 8.0 (i.e. you want to give support for ios 7 also) then you need to set launch screen two time :

1) from launchscreen.storyboard(ios 8.0 and greater) - It is simple view controller. Drag and drop imageview on it and set your image to it

2) from `Assets.xcassets` and new launch screen by clicking `+` button and the from project settings change `launch image source` to that launch screen file you have add in assets

So, if your deployment target is 8.0 or greater then you only need to set from launchscreen.storyboard.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: thanks lion, but how on the launchscreen.storyboard put an image at exactly 20 pixels from the bottom of the status bar (and in the launchscreen the status bar seen to be transparent i don't know if it's matter). I also need to center horizontally this image ? i m very new to xcode :(

Comment: For that you should use autolayout. set constraint like : top,bottom,leading and trailing